# Magento 2: New theme XML files not loaded on live site

Tags: magento2, theme, xml

My new theme works locally, but when once uploaded to live server, selected in the Admin, it shows some content, but it's not using my new XML files. The new `default_head_blocks.xml` defintely isn't being loaded.

Actually, some files are being loaded, but some aren't

Comment: What commands have you ran to deploy/since deployment? Try flushing all static files from the cache management section of the admin, it's a button near the bottom.

Comment: Hi
I uninstalled the site and started again. It's really strange. After installation, I can see the images and stylesheets are being loaded. If I refresh the page, or go to the Admin area, the stylesheets and images disappear. If I then (again) change the folder permissions via the command line, they show again. Then, after updating the site, the styles disappear again – change permissions once again and they re-appear.

Comment: I've run the installation from the command line:


`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /home/hampers/public_html`


Navigated to the installation folder:
`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} + -o -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +`


I then used the installation wizard in the browser.


It says everything's fine, but then the issue above occurs where images aren't appearing and stylesheets stop working (until I update the folder permissions again).


I haven't even bothered to try to add my new theme yet!

Comment: The M2 JS files aren't being loaded now...

Comment: If the base and pub/static URLs are correct then I'm not sure :( I've had a few similar problems with static files missing/not loading. Sometimes clearing caches and deleting var/pre-processed helps, other times it doesn't. I'm having quite a few problems with caching even with all caches disabled, M2 doesn't seem very dev friendly at the moment :(

Comment: It works absoultely fine on my local server (MAMP) though :-(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have performed below operation on your live site:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

and

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

after these all modules which are used in your theme will be installed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, that didn't work. I'm still seeing a couple of my templates being shown on the page, amongst a load of unstyled HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

First remove var/viev_preprocessed and pub/static directories and then do a php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy . Also keep in mind if your site has multiple store languages to add the locales at the end of the deploy command.